# Calculate statistical difference from pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, statistics, pivot-table

I've built this table:

```
s_male  Values              
                    0                                                                       1       
hs_name1            AVERAGE of sat_composite    STDEV of sat_composite  COUNT of s_lasid    AVERAGE of sat_composite    STDEV of sat_composite  COUNT of s_lasid
Hope High School                         986    600                     639                 979                         630                     579
James High School                        837    568                     473                 830                         612                     428
Juniper High School                      789    525                     538                 722                         577                     466
Kennedy High School                      531    468                     314                 523                         484                     239
King High School                         683    540                     275                 619                         569                     258
Lincoln High School                      842    538                     354                 933                         534                     279
Meadowbrook High School                  484    517                     292                 484                         507                     274
North Falls High School                 1056    531                     590                1046                         547                     564
Orange High School                       905    597                     555                 828                         619                     526
Polk High School                         680    569                     567                 691                         568                     501
South Falls High School                  898    602                     488                 904                         584                     461
Upper Hills High School                  457    491                     349                 431                         490                     248
Washington High School                   795    609                     482                 818                         635                     401
Grand Total                              801    585                    5916                 796                         603                    5224
```

Alos pictured here: 
[image]

I now want to calculate if the average SAT_composite score for women (`s_male=0`) is statistically different than for men (`s_male=1`).

I've been trying to figure this out and I am a little lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You _could_ do a paired t-test but much better to go back to the raw data and find out how to do an anova with school as one of the factors and sex as the other (there are add-ons which will do this).

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is just a regular t-test. In google sheets the syntax is:

```
=TTEST(B2:B8,C2:C8,2,2)
```

That will give you the p value associated with the test

[Arguments](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055837):

1. Range for male scores
2. Range for female scores
3. How many tails? 1 or 2
4. Type of t-test. This choice is important and depends on whether certain assumptions have been violated (primarily independence and homoscedasticity)

I would agree with Toms suggestion in the comments about going back to the raw data as you'll be able to better model your data (in your example you've already collapsed across schools by calculating means, which loses information)